# Create a file concatenating strings and values from another file in bash

Tags: bash, loops, concatenation, readline

I need to create a FileToCreate.txt with many rows, which include numerical data values coming

from File1.txt

## FiletoCreate.txt:

```
ncap2 -Oh -s'TOPOBATHY(v1,v2)=v3.'   --- first row

ncap2 -Oh -s'TOPOBATHY(168,361)=20.' --- scnd row

ncap2 -Oh -s'TOPOBATHY(169,366)=22.' ----third row

ncap2 -Oh -s'TOPOBATHY(Vn1,Vn2)=Vn3.'----last nth row
```

File1.txt:

```
v1  v2 v3

168 361 20

169 366 22

.    .   .

Vn1 Vn2  Vn3
```

I tried so far:

```
ifile=file.txt

st='ncap2 -Oh -s 'TOPOBATHY('

st1=')='

st2='.''

line_no=$(wc -l < $ifile)

for row in 'seq 1 $line_no'; do


cat $ifile | awk -v st=$st -v st1=$st1 -v st2=$st2 


'{if (NR==$row) print(st $1 "," $2 st1 $3 st2 st3)}' >> $tmpdir/tmp
```

It is one of my very first scripts and it is very artesanal and does not work. PLease somebody

can guide me ?

Thanks in advance,
Nella

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to see below script works:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read val1 val2 val3
do
  echo "ncap2 -Oh -s'TOPOBATHY($val1,$val2)=$val3.'"
done < file1.txt > FiletoCreate.txt
```

The `while` loop reads the input `file1.txt` line by line and stores the 3 values in val1, val2 & val3 (assuming these values are space separated).

During each iteration of `while`, `echo` prints the values with your strings around it.

The whole `while` output is redirected to `FiletoCreate.txt`.